# how to display a message on cart and checkout page for particular category product?

Tags: customization, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

lets say i have a category "test" and its product "t1". IF i add this product to cart, it must show some message "my custom message". Also on checkout page, how can i do the same on payment step. i.e check if it is from category test then display this message ?

what i tried so far on cart page is this before form on cart.phtml:

```
$_catCollection = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getCategoryCollection();

foreach ($_catCollection as $_category) {
  // do stuff with your Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
  print_r($_category);
}
?>
```

But getting this
**Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object**

Comment: As for your error, that is happening because $this is the Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart object. This class does not have a getItem() method (Although getItems(), it does). Instead you will need to get the items collection and loop through them, since your cart will likely have multiple items. For reference, you may visit the class doc: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Checkout/Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an attribute for each product that will contain your special message.

Then you can maybe do something along the lines of:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) : ?>
      <?php  if ($item->getSpecialMessage) : ?>
           <?php echo $item->getSpecialMessage ?>
      <?php endif ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```